# Styling dataframe if contain string in all columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The objective is to highlight a cell if it contain `*` or `**`.

I have the impression this can be achieved as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ( {'Data': ['foo', '*', 'bar'],
                     'myda': ['**', '*', 'wer']} )


def highlight_ (s, props=''):
    return np.where ( s.str.contains ( "*" ), props, '' )


df.apply ( highlight_, props='background-color:yellow', axis=1 )
```

However, the compiler return an `re.error`.

```
re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

May I know how to properly implement this?

Comment: `s.str.contains ("\*")`. You have to escape the asterisk.

Comment: also i think you want `df.style.apply(...` instead of just `df.apply(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The asterisk needs to be escaped: `'\*'`
2. The highlighting should be applied to `df.style` instead of just `df`

```
def highlight_(s, props=''):
    return np.where(s.str.contains('\*'), props, '')

df.style.apply(highlight_, props='background-color:yellow; color:black;')
```

[image]

---

To differentiate `*` and `**`, try [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def highlight_(s):
    return np.select(
        condlist=[s.str.contains('\*\*'), s.str.contains('\*')],
        choicelist=['background-color:green', 'background-color:purple'],
        default='')

df.style.apply(highlight_)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @tdy. Bit greedy here, but can you suggest how can we have diffrent color for separate case of single and double *

Comment: @balandongiv see if the update works for you